# Image is not downloading using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file, download

I am using the below mentioned code to download image.

```
$image_url='http://www.abcd.com/I_298f02_4766792.jpg';

$doc_root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$image_upload_path = $doc_root . '/';
$image_name2 = 'img-' . time() . '.jpg';

$destination  = $image_upload_path . $image_name2;

$data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

The above mentioned code is working fine in development environment to download image from any website. The code also works in live site to download images from other website except only one site.

The image seems to be downloaded but whenever i am trying to open the image using any image viewer, an error message is being displayed which is given below.

**Could not load image 'img-65456465.jpg'.
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21)**

I checked the error log as well but found no issue.
I am not understanding why its image download functionality is not working with that particular website only.

Note: 
1) I checked that the original image type hosted in that website is JPEG only.

**EDIT:**
When i am trying to view the downloaded image using browser, i found the below mentioned error.

The image 'http://www.my-live-site.com/folder/img-65456465.jpg' can not be displayed because it contains error.

As per suggestion, i am providing the original website link.
**Website:** http://www.funnyjunk.com/
**Image:** any image link from this website. For example http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/The+smarterest.+Wow+a+description+I+could+say+anything+I_298f02_4766792.jpg

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change the fopen() to:

```
$file = fopen($destination, "wb+"); // binary writing
```

Let me know.

**EDIT**

Here's the code that will work:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 0);

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0\r\n" . 
    "Referer: http://www.funnyjunk.com\r\n"
  )
);

$image_url = 'http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/The+smarterest.+Wow+a+description+I+could+say+anything+I_298f02_4766792.jpg';

$doc_root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$image_upload_path = $doc_root . '/';
$image_name2 = 'img-' . time() . '.jpg';

$destination  = $image_upload_path . $image_name2;

$data = file_get_contents($image_url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
//$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
//fputs($file, $data);
//fclose($file);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data;
?>
```

[stream_context_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) with the referrer to the original site did the trick.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Getting the same issue.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Please mention the website url. It should be no issues with an image in it.

Comment: I transferred the downloaded image in my development workspace. I am using UBUNTU in development workspace? But, is it OS dependent? I tried to view the downloaded image using browser as well and found error (Mentioned in above description).

Comment: Image viewing is not OS dependent, but, the file writing can be. In you case, it seems that the images are protected somehow by the site. If you could point me to the site, that would be a help.

Comment: Provided the url on main description. I also thought about protection issue at first. But, if any protection is working, then the code to download image should not work in local site as well.

Comment: In actual, the image is not working, if you hit the image directly, it's creating a redirect to a page and I guess, that's saving. Have you checked the content of the file that's being saved?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37714/discussion-between-debashis-and-anupam)

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine i ve tested with one new url working fine try this code

```
<?php
$image_url='http://blog.svnlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/PHP-DOWNLOAD-FILES-BY-URL.png';

$doc_root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo $doc_root;
$image_upload_path = $doc_root . '/';
$image_name2 = 'img-' . time() . '.jpg';

$destination  = $image_upload_path . $image_name2;

$data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, My code is working fine to download images from almost all website except only one website. And i noticed the above mentioned error message whenever i am trying to open the downloaded image. Shall i mention the website name here? Am i allowed to mention the website link?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided isn't an image when you download it. When you open the image URL in your browser, you're redirected to the HTML page which contains the image. This is confirmed when I run the file command on this image, it tells me it is a HTML text document.

```
piNAS:~#: file The+smarterest.+Wow+a+description+I+could+say+anything+I_298f02_4766792.jpg
The+smarterest.+Wow+a+description+I+could+say+anything+I_298f02_4766792.jpg: HTML document text
```

It's probably set that images can't be directly linked to, and then it redirects you to the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just open your url

http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/The+smarterest.+Wow+a+description+I+could+say+anything+I_298f02_4766792.jpg

and refresh this page. 
you will redirected to someother page i think this is the problem image has been protected.